# How to find $\left\lfloor\sum_{r=1}^{80}\int_0^1x^{\sqrt r-1}dx\right\rfloor$

Tags: integration

> $$\left\lfloor\sum_{r=1}^{80}\int_0^1x^{\sqrt r-1}dx\right\rfloor$$

---

My try:
$$K=\left\lfloor\sum_{r=1}^{80}\int_0^1x^{\sqrt r-1}dx\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\sum_{r=1}^{80}\frac1{\sqrt r}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac1{\sqrt 1}+\frac1{\sqrt 2}+\ldots+\frac1{\sqrt{80}}\right\rfloor$$
I can only say:
$$\left\lfloor\sum_{r=1}^{80}\frac1{\sqrt {80}}\right\rfloor<K<\left\lfloor\sum_{r=1}^{80}\frac1{\sqrt 1}\right\rfloor\\
\lfloor\sqrt{80}\rfloor<K<\lfloor80\rfloor\\
8<K<80$$
So I don't know how to find K?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: You need tighter bounds on $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{r}}$.

Note that $\sqrt{r+1} - \sqrt{r} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{r+1}+\sqrt{r}} < \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{r}} < \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{r}+\sqrt{r-1}} = \sqrt{r} - \sqrt{r-1}$.

Hence, $2(\sqrt{r+1} - \sqrt{r}) < \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{r}} < 2(\sqrt{r} - \sqrt{r-1})$.

Using these bounds will give you two telescoping sums, which are easy to evaluate.

Comment: how did you get that idea, part of some standard topic?

Comment: It's a "common" trick used in math competitions. But its hard to think of it if you haven't seen it before.

Answer (score 5):

Since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is decreasing, we have

$$\int_2^{81} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \,dx < \sum_{k = 1}^{80} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} < \int_1^{81} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \,dx,$$

and evaluating gives

$$2 (9 - \sqrt{2}) < \sum_{k = 1}^{80} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} < 16.$$

Now, $8 < 9$ implies that $\sqrt{2} < \frac{3}{2}$, so we may weaken the first inequality to $$15 = 2 \left(9 - \frac{3}{2}\right) < \sum_{k = 1}^{80} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}},$$ and so $$\left\lfloor \sum_{k = 1}^{80} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \right\rfloor = 15.$$

Comment: Oh something like Lower sum and upper sum, this is simpler but I wish not deaccepting answers for it might be hurting to some, yours is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Aditya A way to avoid these situations is to wait more than **6 minutes** after an answer is posted, to accept it.

Comment: @Aditya No worries, the important thing is that you understand the problem better. I'd opine that JimmyK4542's solution is actually more elementary, as it doesn't involve calculus.

Comment: @Did thnx a good suggestion